# What does 「とある」 mean in these sentences?

Tags: grammar, meaning, particle-と

The following sentence appears in [this video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=DX0X4JZ7MHc&list=PLCJsqOnZYba7THbRVN518XifFurnwAUKr&index=3) at around 7 min:

> 教科書の中でキツツキは木に穴をあける**とありました**が、一秒間のうちに何回どんどんどんどんってできるでしょうか？

The follwing sentence appears [in this answer](https://japanese.stackexchange.com/questions/9847/what-is-the-function-of-%E3%81%A8-in-%E3%81%A8%E3%81%82%E3%82%8B/9942#9942):

> "メニューには売り切れ**とある**" (menu says [it is] sold out.)

I want to know what do 「と」 and 「ある」 mean in these sentences?

In [this Japanese dictionary](https://jisho.org/search/%E3%81%A8%E3%81%82%E3%82%8B), 「とある」 got a meaning:

```
according to; reads; reading; is written; says; states. ​Abbreviation, See also と書いてある
```

but, how does it abbreviate from と書いてある?

Comment: it may have been answered in (but I'm not sure): https://japanese.stackexchange.com/questions/72423/what-is-the-etymology-of-%e3%81%a8%e3%81%82%e3%82%8b and in https://japanese.stackexchange.com/questions/9847/what-is-the-function-of-%e3%81%a8-in-%e3%81%a8%e3%81%82%e3%82%8b?noredirect=1&lq=1

Comment: If I am not mistaken, the meaning here is "it is said that ..." or "it is written that ...". Grammatically the と makes the preceding statement a relative clause (The same grammar as for quoting) on which ある acts.

Comment: Jisho.org states that とある is an abbreviation of と書いてある.

Comment: You've not got the whole sentence there.  She says, 教科書の中で。。。とありました。

Comment: @A.Ellett Thanks for your comment, I've corrected the sentence.

Comment: @Makoto I'm sorry to say but in these answers "とある" is a single word, not と+ある.

Comment: @古手梨花 what makes you think "とある" is a single word?  The particle here is the quotative と and ある here is the usual ある which in this context is a kind of shorthand for saying "[the textbook] says".

Comment: @A.Ellett What I mean "these" is the sentenses in his/her answer listed, not my own question. I apologize..

Answer (score 8, accepted):

～とある can be reworded using ～と書いてある in most of the times, but it doesn't mean that it is the abbreviation of the latter. "The sign reads 'STOP'." is a kind of peculiar grammar too, so to speak, but not an abbreviation of "The sign can be read 'STOP'."

This と is quotative. The so-called "quotative" と isn't just for closing quotations; its real function is to convert an arbitrary language snippet into an adverbial clause in a sentence. Thus the phrase ～と modifies the verb ある.

> 教科書の中でキツツキは木に穴をあけるとありました
> "in the textbook, there was literally 'woodpeckers make holes in trees'"
> = "the textbook had (a content) literally 'woodpeckers make holes in trees'"
> = "the textbook (we saw) says 'woodpeckers make holes in trees'"

Incidentally, the past tense ありました does not mean that it no longer *says* in this context, but they no longer *see* the textbook, as you see in the translation above.